# Multiple Actions to 1 button in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, button, action

What I'm trying to do is, I have a button that opens up the photo library so the user can choose the photo and then the photo is then displayed on another view (another .xib file). How can I do this? Right now, I have both the photo library action and change view action pointing towards the button and its crashing due to both actions happening at once. Is there a pause or anything that I can add?

Answer (score 0):

You should let one IBAction control your behavior, maybe this will help you:

```
    - (IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender {
        if ([fooController respondsToSelector:@selector(showLibrary)]) {
            [fooController performSelector:@selector(showLibrary)];
        }
        if ([barController respondsToSelector:@selector(displayImage:)]) {
            [barController performSelector:@selector(displayImage:) withObject:image afterDelay:0.1];
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want 'removeTarget' and 'addTarget'

```
[self.playPause removeTarget:self
  action:@selector(PausePlayback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.playPause addTarget:self
  action:@selector(PlaybackTrackingData)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```